# Easy way to disable a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

Is there an easy way to disable a `UITextField` in code?

My app has 12 `UITextField` that are all turned on by default, but when a change is detected in my Segment Control I want to disable some of the `UITextField` depending on what Segment the user picks.

Just need to know how to disable it or make it non-editable?

Thanks

Answer (score 114, accepted):

In Objective-C:

```
textField.enabled = NO;
```

In Swift:

```
textField.isEnabled = false
```

Reference: [UIControl.isEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618217-isenabled)

Comment: lol, was sure I tried this all-ready, but I must have made a typo or something because it works.. your a lifesaver... Thanks :)

Comment: If you're ever trying to find out *if* its enabled, keep in mind the getter is textField.isEnabled, not textField.enabled.

Comment: The property `enabled` inherits UIControl's property. if NO, ignores touch events. it's a good work around approach.

Answer (score 30):

If you also want to indicate that the text field is disabled you should add more code:

if using UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect, you can only gray out text:

```
textField.enabled = NO;
textField.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

if using any other style, you can also gray out background:

```
textField.enabled = NO;
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Answer (score 12):

This would be the simplest of all , when you multiple textfields too:

in viewDidLoad:(set the delegate only for textfields which should not be editable.

```
self.textfield.delegate=self;
```

and insert this delegate function:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
return NO;
}
```

Thats it!

Comment: How is this simpler than `textField.enabled = NO`, which was already posted? I didn't -1 this, because it's a legitimate alternate solution that might be more convenient in a couple of edge cases (e.g. if you've got some object that's the delegate of loads of different text fields, and which ones are disabled is changing frequently), but for most scenarios it's definitely not simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: You can always check this way:   'code' if(textfield==self.aTextField){    //check if thats the textfield u want to disable     return NO;    else{

Comment: This is the best solution when you have multiple textfield! Thank you Ankish

Comment: This is also the way to go if you don't want the UITextField to be grayed out.

Answer (score 2):

Make category on UIView.

add following methods in that category.

```
-(void)disable {
    self.alpha = 0.5;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
}

-(void)enable {
    self.alpha = 1.0;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
}
```

then just call

```
yourTextField.disable();
```

Actually,You can use this on any view that you want.

Answer (score -1):

You should conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` and return `false` in this method. This way the text field is still selectable, but it is not available for editing and cutting

Code is in Swift 4

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  return false
}
```

Comment: Actually, it will be still available for everything. The keyboard will open and will accept key-presses, you will get a paste action but text field will ignore it all. From user perspective a terrible solution.

Comment: Sometimes if you want the textfield to open a UIPickerView, this would be a viable solution