# switch function to make page available

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I've searched through the forums and wasn't able to find anything similar to this question. It's my first time posting so please let me know if I need to add anymore information and I'll try my best!

I'm exploring Xcode and building an app for iOS 7 on an iPhone. I'm using a hypothetical purpose for the app just to see if I can learn how to build the thing (it's a booking system for taxis). It's a tabbed application (I have three tabs at the bottom corresponding to three different screens of the app, one is rates which displays a scrollable image of rates, one is a booking system that sends an email with information taken from text fields, and one is a settings page)

My questions is as follows:

On the booking page, I'd like to have a switch that either enables or disables user entry into additional text fields (it's actually for the option to book a 'return' journey, so the user can add in extra information for the return booking).

I have my page set up with the first text fields in place, but I can't for the life of me figure out or find anywhere about how to make this switch enable entry into the additional text fields. Ideally I'd like them to be greyed out and disabled if the switch is off, and enabled if the switch is on.

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

edit:I'm also doing this with storyboard, wasn't sure if this made a difference!

Comment: Duplicate from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599733/easy-way-to-disable-a-uitextfield

Comment: I cant's see how that's a duplicate at all, I want to use a switch to control this, which the other user didn't. As the answers are quite different, this definitely isn't a duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UISwitch` and `UITextField` for this. `UITextField` has a property called `enabled` that controls whether the user can interact with it.

First you need to create an `IBOutlet` for your `UITextField` in storyboard by control-dragging it to respective `@interface` definition in your header file. Then you need to create an `IBAction` for your `UISwitch`, again by control-dragging it to `@interface` (choosing 'Action' for 'Connection' and 'changed' for 'Event').

Finally implement the newly generated method like this:

```
@implementation ViewController
-(void)mySwitchChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *mySwitch=(UISwitch *)sender;
    myTextField.enabled=[mySwitch isOn];     
}
.
.
```