# Setting UITextField not editable or editable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to know how to disable `UITextField`, i.e I placed a `UIButton` in the frame of `UITextField` for design purpose.

When I tap my button in `UITextField` the keyboard appears, but I don't want the keyboard to be displayed!

Here is my code so far:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    return textField !=textfiled1;
    return textField !=textfiled2;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to disable a UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599733/easy-way-to-disable-a-uitextfield)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can enable or disable user interaction on the textfield using this property:

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

In Swift 5

```
textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: In swift 5 I use this: itemTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: @papesky don't you mean " = false"

Answer (score 12):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  return NO;
}
```

You can use this too

Comment: This solution is more reliable as disabling userInteraction might have other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer in Swift 4:

```
textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `UIButton` is not on `UITextField`. so `bringToFromView` first then your `UIButton` selector method called first. Because compiler check `Event` in hierarchy.  if first control response the event then it wan't looking for next.

I have tested your scenario and its working fine at my end.

Answer (score 0):

swift version of my Obj-C Answer

```
   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below property.

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score -2):

you can achieve this with the help of: 
If you want to disable editing you can do this 
`textField.editable = NO;`

and if you want to make it editable again you can do this
`textField.editable = YES;`

Comment: I think you confused `UITextView` with `UITextField`.