# how to block user from changing text field

Tags: ios, xcode6, uitextfield

I have two text fields that I don't want the user to change. Is there a way to do this in Xcode 6? I have already entered text in the text field but when I simulate the app the user is still able to modify it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to disable a UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599733/easy-way-to-disable-a-uitextfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return 'NO' for the delegate method:

```
`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`.
```

or disable the textField, that may alter the appearance.

`textField.enabled = NO`

or use a `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

Make category on UIView.

add following methods in that category.

```
-(void)disable {
    self.alpha = 0.5;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
}

-(void)enable {
    self.alpha = 1.0;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
}
```

then just call

```
yourTextField.disable();
```

Actually,You can use this on any view that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Return NO for above method

```
   optional func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
                replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

Or set textfield disable and userInteractionDisable

```
textfield.userInteractionEnabled = false
textfield.enabled = false
```